# Max number of open mapped memory files

Tags: c++, .net, mapping

I am working on a process that utilizes mapped memory files for cross application communication.

I have some users who are seeing errors that appear to be caused by the OS not allowing anymore mapped memory files.

My question is, what is the max number of mapped memory files you can have open? Is there a way to query and get this number?

From what I can tell it varies machine to machine. One user saw the error at about 15 while another at 40.

Comment: Depends on the OS. Which one are you using?

Comment: The quantity may also depend on the available memory on the platform.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. From what I was already able to gather there is some variances between machines. What I am looking for is a way to know ahead of time what the limit it. This way instead of my process breaking down I can better handle failing to create the mapped memory file.

Comment: @RichardEagle Why you need to know the limit in advance? What if it's a moving target? Isn't it better to detect failure at creation time and handle the case appropriately?